# How to say more about parameter estimates

Tags: statistical-significance, estimation, t-test, error

I have obtained some parameter estimates and corresponding t-values. How can I use the t-values to say more about the significance of these estimates? For example, if t = \hat{\beta} / s.e.(\beta), then are larger values for t better or worse? What is the estimation error? I am confused in how to interpret their values.

Can someone recommend me a website or book where this is explained?

Thanks!

PS. If in the hypothetical equation Y = aX + e the error e is normally distributed with mean zero and variance (\sigma_e)^2, does that mean that a is normally distributed as well? Because from my understanding one needs a distribution for the parameter in order to apply a significance test, right?

Comment: This is pretty broad... I guess you should start with some (any) statistics handbook, since your question asks in general how does hypothesis testing work and this is covered in any introductory book.

Comment: Are you working on empirical data ? t- statistic is computed for different purposes  e.g. to test difference between sample-statistics and population statistic. Also, you are talking about fixed-effects model. Try to indicate a concrete problem.

Comment: @subhash I am dealing with parameter estimates from a Kalman Filter procedure. I started from a theoretical model, obtained data, and estimated the parameters including unobserved states. The question now is, how 'valuable' are these parameter estimates?

Comment: What  is extra or more  in your  mind  ?  Do you have anything to say on closing  as duplicate.